# Copy the data in a cell into created sheet

Tags: excel, vba

My code is supposed to create extra sheets and duplicate the data accordingly based on the data in the cell.

```vb
Sub create_category()

Dim cell As Range
Dim wsname As Worksheet
Dim test As Boolean

For Each cell In Sheets("Data").Range("d4", Range("d" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    test = False

    For Each wsname In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        If wsname.name = cell Then test = True
    Next wsname
    
    If test = False Then Sheets.Add after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    ActiveSheet.name = cell
        
    Sheets(cell.name).Range("d3").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0) = cell         
Next cell

Sheets("Data").Select

End Sub
```

The program performed until I added the line of code before `Next cell`.

The error 1004 is indicated on `For Each cell IN Sheets("Data").Range.....`.

Sheets are created with the same name as the cell. I want to copy the cell with the same name as the sheet into the sheets thus me using `cell.name`.

Comment: I think you neeed to sort the formatting and also indicate which line gives the error.

Comment: What are you expecting to get from `cell.name`? Instead maybe: `cell.Worksheet.Range("d3")` but it's not clear what you are expecting.

Comment: So sheets were created with the same name as the cell so I want to copy the cells  with the same name as the sheet into the sheets  thus me using cell.name and thank you.

Comment: well that's just the thing... cells do not have a name. Maybe `cell.Value` ?

Answer (score 2):

When you write

```
Sheets("Data").Range("d4", Range("d" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
```

VBA will try to create a Range on your sheet "Data". Start of the Range is cell D4. For the end of the Range, you write `Range("d" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)`, but you don't tell VBA from which sheet you want to access this cell. And while it seems to be obvious for you, it is not for VBA. It will read the cell from the active sheet, and that will result in an invalid range definition which thows a 1004.

**Always** specify on which sheet you want to work, for *every* access of `Range` or `Cells`.

I would suggest to use intermediate variables to make it easier to debug. Note the dot (`.`) in front of `Range` and `Rows`.

```
Dim lastCell as Range, dataRange as Range
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
    Set lastCell = .Range("d" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
    Set dataRange = .Range("D4", lastCell)
End With
For Each cell in dataRange
    ...
Next cell
```

**Update** Your following code also has issues. Change the loop to

```
For Each cell In dataRange
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = getWorksheet(cell.Value)
    ws.Range("d3").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0) = cell.Value
Next cell
```

And add the following function

```
Function getWorksheet(sheetname As String) As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set getWorksheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheetname)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If getWorksheet Is Nothing Then
        Set getWorksheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
        getWorksheet.Name = sheetname
    End If
End Function
```

However I am not sure about the logic: The current code will write the name of the sheet (cell.Value) into the sheet - I doubt that is what you want.

Comment: Thank you very much I never would of thought it would be such a minor technical issue